# Are dynamite shocks specific to Angry Birds Space Level 1-27?

Tags: angry-birds-space

In Angry Birds Space level 1-27, the shock of blowing up the dynamite box on one side of the planetoid immediately causes the dynamite box on the opposite side to blow up also, without anything falling on it first. For example, see this [walk-through video](http://www.youtube.com/embed/RygZ1kjmuw0?autoplay=1&hd=1) .  I've also hit the opposite dynamite box first and it works the same way on this level.  As an avid Angry Birds player this behaviour surprised me because it was unexpected considering classic vicinity triggers for dynamite.

Is this shock-wave behaviour level-specific to Space 1-27, or does dynamite have that effect in general in AB Space physics?

As a comparison point, I can have two dynamite boxes in much nearer vicinity on the same plane in classic Angry Birds and they won't trigger one another to explode immediately.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

See the little red lights on top of the boxes?  Those are some kind of transmitters, and that's why when one gets blown the other does too.  When they aren't present you won't see this behavior in Angry Birds Space.  The other games have similar mechanics, but I don't think it's quite as explicit visually.  Perhaps it will make it into a future update to the original game or Seasons :)

Comment: I hadn't realized those lights were transmitters or connected in any way. Cool. That makes a lot more sense now. Thanks.